# Listing down stored records localStorage | Google Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, for-loop, google-chrome-extension

How do I get to list down the stored records in the for loop?

Basically I want it to list down the records like this:

```
'<div id="record_' + number + '">' + localstorage value + '</div>'
```

The number in the class should add 1 every record, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4 every record it lists down, and so on.

The localstorage value should show the localStorage[] but the problem is, the localStorage name has the same, e.g.

(*clicks on button*)

it will save the value of the URL into a localStorage

I then open the application and shows the window.html

inside there is list of stored records by using this:

```
'<div id="record_' + number + '">' + localstorage value + '</div>'
```

INCLUDING the record number to add per record 1, 2, 3, etc... like this:

```
<div id="record_1">localstorage value</div>
<div id="record_2">localstorage value</div>
<div id="record_3">localstorage value</div>
<div id="record_4">localstorage value</div>
<div id="record_5">localstorage value</div>
<div id="record_6">localstorage value</div>

etc...
```

**EDIT:**

```
for (var i = 1; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
document.write('<div id="record_' + i + '">' + i + '<span style="float:right;"><ahref="#" onclick="javascript:clear(' + i + ');">Delete</a></span></div>');
}

window.addEventListener("load", windowLoaded, false);
function windowLoaded() 
{
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) 
  {
    var btn = '<a href="' + tab.url + '" onclick="Save(\'' + tab.url + '\');">Add to Favourites</a>';
    document.getElementById('current-link').innerHTML = '<p>' + btn + '</p>';
  });
}

function Save(url)
{
    localStorage.setItem("cilium-favs", url);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate localStorage as well.

```
for (var i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  console.log(localStorage.key(i));
}
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: I've edited the code above, I can't get it to save the url into the localstorage, please provide me some examples, I hardly can find good tutorials for good storage instead of chrome documentation all the time. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? Have you attempted to debug it in the Inspector and figure out where in the code breaks?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more what he was looking for.  A couple of years late, but Mohamed Mansour's answer helped me, and this might help others.

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  var key = localStorage.key(i);
  console.log(i, key, localStorage[key]);
}
```